# Android App Interfacing with IMAP and populating with Gmail emails

Tags: android, email, imap

I am trying to make an application which will basically be the same as the stock email app. To allow me to log into an email account using IMAP and SMTP. I have been trying to understand the protocols and how to interface them with an app, but am at a loss. Can anyone possibly guide me to a solution or a direct download for the source of the stock app?